# php compile oci8 and stuck only at checking dynamic linker characteristics?? Why stuck?

Tags: php, linux, oracle

./configure -with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-suse-linux
checking host system type... x86_64-suse-linux
checking target system type... x86_64-suse-linux
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php5/extensions
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.12.0 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for Oracle (OCI8) support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 5.2.5, ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for long int... yes
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64
checking Oracle Instant Client version... 11.1
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld
itec-res1(psinl)(ELG/R):~/liew/php/oci8/source/oci8-1.4.1 -> ./configure -with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-suse-linux
checking host system type... x86_64-suse-linux
checking target system type... x86_64-suse-linux
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php5/extensions
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.12.0 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for Oracle (OCI8) support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 5.2.5, ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for long int... yes
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64
checking Oracle Instant Client version... 11.1
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... fort
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether fort accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for fort option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if fort PIC flag -fPIC works... no
checking if fort static flag -static works... yes
checking if fort supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the fort linker (/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics...

Comment: `checking for Oracle (OCI8) support... yes, shared`: What is the problem?

Comment: it got stuck on the last part
checking dynamic linker characteristics...

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not explain this issue clearly I think that I have a solution for you. I tried to hack the oci8 extension into php on my 64bit linux but after several hours of trying...fruitlessly I gave up installing it from source.

I had a problem with the oracle instant client and because there were no usable .deb packages form my Linux Mint i tried to use [Alien](http://www.icewalkers.com/Linux/Software/57020/Alien.html) to convert .rpm to .deb and it worked. After that I was able to install oci8 without problem.

Before that the compilation got stuck where you have the problem.